# Was there a hype during the 60s, 70s and 80s to name bands according to insects?

Tags: bands, the-beatles, names

Well, has anyone noticed that the bands that made it to top of the music charts during 60s to 80s seem to be insect-named? (Do I need to explain this?)

Examples:

- The Beatles
- Bee Gees
- Queen (indirectly as queen-bee)

And as a connecting question, did the latter bands (I am assuming, The Beatles started all of this) just named it according to insects because The Beatles has already became famous with the use of insect-band name?

Comment: Buddy Holly and *The Crickets*?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure someone has noticed.

Comment: Queen was not named after queen bees.

Comment: So three examples, two of which aren't relevant, for a three decade period is supposed to indicate a "hype"?

Comment: @BCdotWEB I think that the question was clearly stated as "hype during the..", and not as "hype that span the years from 1960 to 1980".  Anyway, somebody else already understood the question and at least, these people don't question a question.

Comment: @BlueDeeper Even ignoring the time period, let me repeat: "three examples, two of which aren't relevant". Even if they all were relevant, it's still merely three examples. Three is not a hype. WRT "at least, these people don't question a question": they should, they should have downvoted it and they certainly shouldn't have answered it. And their answers aren't answers, because your question is irrelevant.

Comment: @BCdotWEB First of all, I never could not comprehend why my question became irrelevant.  It was an honest inquiry about something which I don't know - hence the question "was there a hype?".  If there exists a number of "relevant" examples that other people here in stack exchange know, then, you would agree then that there was a hype.  But based on currently existing answers, they couldn't prove that there was a hype, then I guess the precise answer to my question is - "No, there wasn't any hype".  Can't my question be interpreted as simple as that?

Answer (score 5):

I'd submit that short of Buddy Holly's backing band, The Beatles, Iron Butterfly and Adam and the Ants, there really weren't many insect-related band names at all.  Queen had nothing to do with insects and everything to do with being grandiose, and The Bee Gee's was about being Brothers Gibb (B.G.).

Not surprisingly, there were no bands named after insects once Black Flag formed.  ;o)

Comment: Oh, I thought you said "Black Frog", cause that could have explained it.  You know, frogs eat insects, right? Haha. just for laughs, no offense please.

Comment: Well, Black Flag is an anti-insect spray.  I know it's in the US, might not be available in your part of the world.

Comment: You missed Ziggy Stardust & the Spiders from Mars ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin No, spiders are arachnids, not insects.

Comment: -1 for pedantry in the face of lightness

Comment: +1 for using "pedantry" in a sentence.  :o)

Answer (score 3):

Buddy Holly and the Crickets were an influential early rock group whose careers were brought short due to a tragic plane crash.  The Beatles were named [partially in tribute to the Crickets](http://abbeyrd.best.vwh.net/named.htm).

Any other bands with similar names were likely named in tribute to one or both of these bands, given their visibility and influence.  (As Johnny mentioned, however, most of your other examples don't hold up.)